# Error: Value min is not a member of (Int, Int)

Tags: scala, tuples, rdd, minimum

I am trying to produce the RDD that contains an array of tuples that has country names as the first element, and the minimum integer of the tuple as the second element.

I have this code here.

```
val test = sc.parallelize(Array(("US", (4,2)), ("France", (1,2)), ("Italy", (2,3))))
```

I want to store a variable to a value that looks like this:

```
Array( ("US", 2), ("France", 1), ("Italy", 2) )
```

I tried to use this code, but it produced a 'Value min is not a member of (Int, Int)' error.

```
val test1 = test.map(x => (x._1, x._2.min))
```

How to get minimum of `Tuple2[Int, Int]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the minimum of numeric elements in a Tuple `(x, y)`, you could use `x min y`:

```
val test = sc.parallelize(Array(("US", (4,2)), ("France", (1,2)), ("Italy", (2,3))))

test.map(t => (t._1, t._2._1 min t._2._2)).collect
// res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((US,2), (France,1), (Italy,2))
```

For readability, an alternative is to use `case` partial function, as follows:

```
test.map{ case (country, (t1, t2)) => (country, t1 min t2) }
```